# Tracking RTP data by Industry - Google Analytics

Tags: google, analytics, data

I linked my Google Analytics report to my Marketo data and am loving the new visibility.

Is there a way to reproduce Google Analytics' behavior flow based on the industry (or any other Marketo field) of my Marketo leads? Ultimately, it would be extremely useful to be able to filter all of the GA reports based on specific criteria from the leads.

Thanks in advance for your helpfulness!